# Cookie policy for translations

Tags: php, cookies

I haven't understood very well the topic about the cookies. In my webpage I have 4 flags in the footer like this:

[image]

When you click on them, a very simple php script is executed and it creates a cookie with a parameter for the language (us, it, ger, fre). In short, I am using cookies ONLY to save the user preference about the language that will be displayed in the website.

I have read that the user must see a message (and he also must be able to close it) that say "hey I am going to use cookies here, check this link for more info". Here I am **not** going to store particular data, only a php string with a length of 3 at most.

In this case, do I have to show a message about cookies or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie law is rather simple. Look at the citation from the link below.

"Compliance with the cookie law comes down to three basic steps:

Work out what cookies your site sets, and what they are used for, with a cookie audit
Tell your visitors how you use cookies.
Obtain their consent, such as by using Optanon, and give them some control."

https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/

(Basically, the user must be informed that you use a cookie, and then you can make a page where the user can see what you use your cookies for.)

If your website uses cookies, you have to inform the user about it (if your audience is intended for people within EU)

Comment: So in my case I have to tell the user "I am using cookies to save your language settings. No other ways"?

Comment: **"This site is using cookies to remember your language preferences and optimize functionality"**  you can write something like **"By using this site, you consent to the use of cookies for...."**